# How to auto login a new user after registration process?

Tags: php, symfony

I need the new user to auto login just after he finish register. but it seems that symfony not has the document about this.

what i can do is only to let user operate login again using the symfony3 [security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html).

Comment: [Sessions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html).

Comment: And why would u wanna do that? what if they are using a fake email to register?